# Need to Default select an Angular JS Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I am trying to create a set of radio buttons.  Creating the buttons was the easy part, but I am having problems figuring out how to default select one of them without breaking everything.  I have read about using ngChecked in the Angular docs and on multiple other stackoverflow questions but still can't quite seem to figure it out.

What I need to do is have one of the descriptions preselected when the user comes to the page. The price, discount, and deal_value also need to be shown with the values from the preselected price_option object.

Here is the code that I am trying to get to work: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/311/

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController" ng-init="init([{qty: 1, price:10, qty_description:'descrip 1', discount:'1%', deal_value:200}, {qty: 2, price:7, qty_description:'descrip 2', discount:'5%', deal_value:100}])">  

       <div>
           <label ng-repeat="price_option in price_options">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="init.price_option" ng-value="price_option" ng-checked="selected_price_option" name="quantity"/>
              {{ price_option.qty_description }}
           </label>
           <ul>
              <li>{{ init.price_option.price }}</li>
              <li>{{ init.price_option.discount }}</li>
              <li>{{ init.price_option.deal_value }}</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.init = function(prices) {
    $scope.price_options = prices;
    $scope.selected_price_option = $scope.price_options[0];
  };
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <!-- ng-init functionality belongs in controller -->
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <!-- move ng-repeat to container div instead of label -->
        <div ng-repeat="price_option in price_options">
            <label>
                <!-- the model is the scope variable holding the selected value -->
                <!-- the value is the value of this particular option -->
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected_price_option" ng-value="price_option" name="quantity" />{{price_option.qty_description}}</label>
            <ul>
                <li ng-bind="price_option.price"></li>
                <li ng-bind="price_option.discount"></li>
                <li ng-bind="price_option.deal_value"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).
controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    //moved init logic to controler
    $scope.price_options = [{
        qty: 1,
        price: 10,
        qty_description: 'descrip 1',
        discount: '1%',
        deal_value: 200
    }, {
        qty: 2,
        price: 7,
        qty_description: 'descrip 2',
        discount: '5%',
        deal_value: 100
    }];
    $scope.selected_price_option = $scope.price_options[1];
});
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8KH7/2/

Or you can use the object strategy to avoid having to reference $parent: http://jsfiddle.net/W8KH7/3/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I am trying to get this to work using the initializer function but can't figure out the scoping with init().  I need the initializer bc I am passing information via ruby from the view to set the price_options.

Comment: You can just run code then in ng-init like you would in the controller excpet you omit `$scope`. `ng-init="price_options=[{qty: 1,price: 10,qty_description: 'descrip 1',discount: '1%',deal_value: 200}, {qty: 2,price: 7,qty_description: 'descrip 2',discount: '5%',deal_value: 100}];selected_price_option = price_options[1]"`.

Comment: This revision shows the same functionality as revision 3 except uses ng-init: http://jsfiddle.net/W8KH7/4/

Comment: Whew, finally got it working! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

General suggestion, avoid using '{{}}' use ng-bind (This will not related to question, its just good practice )

Use

```
ng-value="true"
```

If you want to control from controller.js then use

```
ng-checked="default_option"
```

and control it in controller.js

```
$scope.default_option = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I updated my code to use ng-bind instead of '{{}}'

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.priceOptions = [
        {qty: 1, price: 10, qty_description: 'Descrip 1', discount: '1%', deal_value: 200}, 
        {qty: 2, price: 7, qty_description: 'Descrip 2', discount: '5%', deal_value: 100}
    ];
    $scope.selected = {priceOption: $scope.priceOptions[0]};
});
```

HTML

```
<label ng-repeat="priceOption in priceOptions">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected.priceOption" ng-value="priceOption" name="quantity" />
    {{ priceOption.qty_description }}
</label>
<ul>
    <li>{{ selected.priceOption.price }}</li>
    <li>{{ selected.priceOption.discount }}</li>
    <li>{{ selected.priceOption.deal_value }}</li>
</ul>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/313/