# Select default radio button option based on value coming from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am writing a quiz engine using angularjs and have been able to successfully load question with the options and have also implemented the NEXT and BACK button which works fine now but then I want it that when a user click the BACK or NEXT button it comes pre-selected with the previous selection made if the question has been answered.

Each of the questions have 4 options, and I have a property on the choices name 'IsSelected' which I am using to determine the previous option taken by the user.

**I want it so that when the user is cross checking answers, any of the previous option chosen should come checked by default which is where I am stuck at the moment. I have seen this question**

[Need to Default select an Angular JS Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846693/need-to-default-select-an-angular-js-radio-button)
 which addresses something similar in terms of setting a default value but not exactly this.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-5" data-ng-repeat="item in items" style=" border:#000 1px solid;padding:10px 40px 40px 40px">
        <h3 style="color: #0000ff">Question <b style="color:red">{{item.QId}}</b> of <b style="color:green">{{item.QCount}}</b></h3>
        <div>


            <!--<div id="first">{{item.QId}}</div>-->
            <h2>{{item.QId}}. {{item.QText}} </h2>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-repeat="choice in item.AnswerCh">

            <input type="radio" name="choize" data-ng-model="choice.IsSelected" value="choice.IsSelected" /> {{choice.Text}}

        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="ref" style="display: none">{{item.QId}}</div>
        <div id="you">{{choice.choize.Text}}</div>
```

JS Code:

```js
        $scope.getNext = function () {    
            var quet = $('#ref').html();
            var answ = $('#you').html();
            cbtFact.getNext().update({q:answ,v:quet },
            function (data, status, headers, config){         
                $scope.items = [];
                
                $scope.items = data;
            },
            function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
        };

        $scope.getPrevious = function () {
            var quet = $('#ref').html();
            var answ = $('#you').html();
            cbtFact.getPrevious().update({ q: answ, v: quet },
            function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items = [];
                $scope.items = data;
             
            function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });

        };
```

Comment: Your code snippet not working, please make jsFiddle so we can help you..... :http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Prog I have created a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kennymore007/dv6cfcud/ , I want the one that IsSelected=true to be selected by default. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `ng-if` like this..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv6cfcud/58/)

```
<div data-ng-repeat="choice in item.AnswerCh">
   <span ng-if="choice.IsSelected">
      <input type="radio" name="choize" data-ng-model="choice.IsSelected" value="choice.IsSelected" checked/> {{choice.Text}}
   </span>
   <span ng-if="!choice.IsSelected">
      <input type="radio" name="choize" data-ng-model="choice.IsSelected" value="choice.IsSelected" /> {{choice.Text}}
   </span>
</div>
```

or use Angular Js `ngChecked` attribute

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv6cfcud/59/)

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="choice in item.AnswerCh">    
     <input type="radio" name="choize" data-ng-model="choice.IsSelected" value="choice.IsSelected" data-ng-checked="choice.IsSelected" /> {{choice.Text}}    
 </div>
```

Update:

using `ng-model` and `ng-value`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv6cfcud/56/)

Though both the above code is working, it has got some issues for working along with `ng-model`.

As per Angular Js [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) this functionality  can be achieved using ng-model and ng-value itself like this and so this should be the *recommended*  way .
`ng-value` should be the value to which the expression should be set when selected.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="choice in item.AnswerCh">
        <input type="radio" name="choize" data-ng-model="choice.IsSelected" ng-value="true" /> {{choice.Text}}       
 </div>
```

Comment: I have tried ngIf it didn't give me the desired result. I have created a fiddle jsfiddle.net/kennymore007/dv6cfcud. I want it to select the one whose IsSelected=true by default. Thank you

Comment: Actually logic is working if you change to higher version of Angular in same fiddle, also we have to change the checked to ngChecked

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to include the logic and upgraded to a higher angular version and still not working. Do I need to change the data type or what? Pls can you help clone the fiddle and show me what's going wrong there? Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the examples. They are quite clear, only that once I change the model to choice.IsSelected using the third fiddle(the one that combines ng-model and ng-value). I don't get the value of the Text property of the selection any longer. How can I get the text property of the option selected? I need the selection to be posted to the server. I have tried to sort it out to no avail. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll check it again, Mean while It doesn't hurt to up vote if you found examples useful.

Comment: Oh I totally skipped my mind, I was going to. I just did. Really useful.