# ng--repeat Radio button default check

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to the angularjs. I have a set of radio buttons and respective values I am displaying using ng-repeat and I want the first radio button to be checked by default.

```
<div class="form-group form-radio" ng-repeat="insr in oneClickDtls.response.investAndInsrStrategy.insuranceOptions">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 visible-sm visible-md">
     <div class="radio padding-top12 padding-bottom12">
        <input class="form-input" type="radio" id="rb_{{$index}}" name="insuranceOptionTab" value="{{insr.coverId}}" ng-model="oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.insuranceOptionsSubmit.coverID">
        <label class="form-label bold-one-click" for="rb_{{$index}}">{{insr.coverAmt | currency}} | {{insr.premium | currency}}</label>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: You can make use of ngInit (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit )here  or if you can show us the controller function we will be able to help you

Comment: This question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846693/need-to-default-select-an-angular-js-radio-button

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$index` to select first input

Like:

```
ng-checked="$index==0?true:false"


<input ng-checked="$index==0?true:false">
```

If you also want to set the ng-model value, then you will need to initialize ng-model value to the first item in the iteration and then checking the input based on the ng-model value.

example:

```
<input ng-checked="yourModel==iterationItem" />
```

where `yourModel` is the ng-model and `iterationItem` will be the iteration item.

Comment: I don't believe `ng-checked` will set the model value, though. It might be better to initialize the default value in the controller.

Comment: Of course it will not set the model value. But OP asked only to set the first value as default. Although, if OP wants to set the model value, it can be done by initialising it in the controller and then checking the corresponding iteration in input

Comment: You can shorten it to <input ng-checked="$index === 0">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- In your javascript, set the default value for the ng-model (oneClick.submitOneClickDetails.insuranceOptionsSubmit.coverID), as the first value of your radio buttons.